An error occurs when compiling a third-party library using swig
I have a C++ portable bag third-party library whose function is camera acquisition. I hope to call it in python. First, I wrote the swigtest.h file and swigtest.cpp file:
#pragma once

#include <iostream>

class CTest
{
public:
    void Version();
};

#include "swigtest.h"
#include "swigtest.h"
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <gigex/gigex.h> //this is  third-party include file
using namespace std;
void CTest::Version()
{
        std::cout << "2024.07.19" << std::endl;
        cv::Mat image = cv::imread("d:/1.jpg");
        printf("%d, %d", image.rows, image.cols);
        CGigeVision gv; //this is  third-party class
}

Then I wrote the example.i file
%module SwigTest
 
%include <opencv.i>
%include "std_vector.i"
%include "std_string.i"

%cv_instantiate_all_defaults

%template(StrVector) std::vector<std::string>;
%{
#include "SwigTest.h"
%}
%include "SwigTest.h"

Finally, use swig to compile and generate cxx and py files.
An error occurs after importing swigtest：
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\simple.py", line 1, in <module>
    import SwigTest
  File "E:\vsproc\opencvdemo\opencvdemo\opencvdemo\SwigTest.py", line 12, in <module>
    import _SwigTest
ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit__SwigTest)


我希望可以正常import swigtest并且没有出错


post the commands you are using, this is probably a problem with the compilation, something like not importing the correct file - SWIG for Python generates multiple files
